# WPF Controls and SystemColors - Alpha Blend?

Tags: .net, wpf, windows, xaml

As far as I can work out, a simple WPF App built in VS 2013 ***appears*** to use SystemColors for various UI elements. For example, the when hovering over an unselected tab in a tab control, the tab seems to take on the MenuHighlight system colour, *but* with an alpha blend applied.

If I restyle a control with a new template/triggers/etc, how do I colour its behaviours like the other controls on the window?  I can obtain a system colour, but that doesn't reveal any alpha level used.

Am I mistaken? How do I achieve the goal of having a standard machine-consistent appearance without hardcoding any values?

Update: I've done some digging and this is what I've found for myself.

[image: Various colours achievable by different means]

The graphic shows the standard WPF MenuItem in hover-over mode at the top, followed by a selection of SystemColors etc, and finally at the bottom #3D26A0DA.

That value was what I found hard-coded by dumping the stock MenuItem's ControlTemplate.  As you can see, that's the colour which matches the menu at the top (and which does not correspond to any SystemColor), with an alpha value as I suspected.

I seriously cannot believe I have to hard-code that "#3D26A0DA" in my own apps to fit in with the appearance of the WPF controls "out of the box".  I may be new to WPF, but I've been programming Windows since version 1.1 and I just know that can't be right. So where is it?  Is it a global resource somewhere?

Comment: How did you establish that the MenuHightlight is an 'alpha blend'?  I observe it as #ff3399ff which is full alpha.

Comment: Just by looking - I've done more research and discovered exactly what the value is. Please see the re-edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had this same issue, fortunately a coworker explained that there is an easier way to access the system colors used.

For example, the MenuHighlightBrush can be accessed by using [{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuHighlightBrushKey}}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.menuhighlightbrushkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is a link to the full list of the different system color references [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.SystemColors(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.SystemColors%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hopefully this is helpful